# How to fix placeholder of intlTelInput plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, intl-tel-input

I'm using the "mask" feature (from [plugin jquery mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) ) and the plugin [intlTelInput](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input).
The problem is that when changing the country selection, the Placeholder is incorrect. Example: if the selection is in the country Brazil, with the placeholder (11) 96123-4567, and when switching to any other country like Botswana and returning the selection to Brazil again, the placeholder is (11) 96123, which is incorrect.
[image: problem execution]

My code is below:

```
// Make sure to place this snippet in the footer or at least after
// the HTML input we're targeting.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var phoneInputID = "#phone";
  var input = document.querySelector(phoneInputID);
  var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
    // allowDropdown: false,
    // autoHideDialCode: false,
    // autoPlaceholder: "off",
    // dropdownContainer: document.body,
    // excludeCountries: ["us"],
    formatOnDisplay: true,
    initialCountry: "BR",
    // geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
    //   $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
    //     var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
    //     callback(countryCode);
    //   });
    // },
    hiddenInput: "full_number",
    // initialCountry: "auto",
    // localizedCountries: { 'de': 'Deutschland' },
    // nationalMode: false,
    // onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
    // placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
    preferredCountries: ['es'],
    // separateDialCode: true,
    utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
  });


  $(phoneInputID).on("countrychange", function(event) {

    // Get the selected country data to know which country is selected.
    var selectedCountryData = iti.getSelectedCountryData();

    // Get an example number for the selected country to use as placeholder.
    newPlaceholder = intlTelInputUtils.getExampleNumber(selectedCountryData.iso2, true, intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.INTERNATIONAL),

      // Reset the phone number input.
      iti.setNumber("");

    // Convert placeholder as exploitable mask by replacing all 1-9 numbers with 0s
    mask = newPlaceholder.replace(/[1-9]/g, "0");

    // Apply the new mask for the input
    $(this).mask(mask);
  });


  // When the plugin loads for the first time, we have to trigger the "countrychange" event manually, 
  // but after making sure that the plugin is fully loaded by associating handler to the promise of the 
  // plugin instance.

  iti.promise.then(function() {
    $(phoneInputID).trigger("countrychange");
  });

});
```

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.12/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.12/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" />
</body>

</html>
```

The solution would be for the Placeholder to be correct when changing selection.